# Empty value in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to send an object for one action with a tag, but this returns an empty array and I don't edit my object because all of its properties are empty (for example: `id` is empty, `title` is empty , etc.).

```
Route::get('/edit/{game}','GameController@edit');
Route::post('/create','GameController@handleCreate');
Route::bind('Game', function($id)
{
    return Game::where('id', $id)->first();
});
```

Code from `index.blade.php`:

```
<td>
    <a href="{{action('GameController@edit',$game->id)}}" class="btn btn-default" value="{{$game->id}}">Edit</a>
    <a href="{{action('GameController@delete',$game->id)}}" class="btn btn-default">Delete</a>
</td>
```

And the relevant controller code:

```
public function edit(Game $game)
{
    // $game = $game->whereId($game1->id)->first();
    // $oldgame = var_dump($game);
    // return $game;

    return view('edit', compact('game'));
}

public function handleEdit(Request $request)
{
    // return $request->title;

    $game = Game::find($request->id);

    // return $game;

    $game->title = $request->title;
    $game->publisher = $request->publisher;
    $game->complete = $request->has('complete');
    $game->save();

    return redirect()->action('GameController@index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's case sensitive. You have {"g"ame} in your routes and "G"ame in your binding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
Route::bind('Game', function($id)
```

to this:

```
Route::bind('game', function($id)
```